# PayPalのAPIエラーコード10002(Security header is not valid)

Tags: paypal

PayPalのAPIを呼び出す際に、Security header is not valid 10002のエラーが出ました、どこかに問題があるのでしょうか。

下記、PayPalからのレスポンスです：
TIMESTAMP=2016-05-10T03:56:19Z
CORRELATIONID=5381abcd3dbea
ACK=Failure
VERSION=109.0
BUILD=22331161
L_ERRORCODE0=10002
L_SHORTMESSAGE0=Security error
L_LONGMESSAGE0=Security header is not valid
L_SEVERITYCODE0=Error

Comment: http://note.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/detail/n384945

Comment: http://qiita.com/PayPal_MTS/items/05ddde06b7095cb49338

Comment: ご自身の回答が十分な物であるならば、回答を「承認」して下さい。回答後48時間たてば[自身の回答でも承認可能](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/01/accept-your-own-answers/)です。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

エラーコード10002はAPI署名などが正しくない場合が出ますので、
下記手順でもう一度APIユーザー名、パスワード、署名を確認し、修正すればエラーが出なくなると思います。

www.paypal.comでログインして、「個人設定>販売ツール>API アクセス」で更新をクリックします。
または、下記URLにアクセスします：
https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/customerprofileweb?cmd=_profile-api-access
表示されている「APIアクセス」画面で「API署名の表示」リンクをクリックしたら、API署名が表示されます。

また、10002エラーの詳細については下記を参考してくだい。
https://www.paypal-knowledge.com/infocenter/index?page=content&id=FAQ1030&pmv=print&impressions=false&viewlocale=ja_JP

https://www.paypal-knowledge.com/infocenter/index?page=content&id=FAQ1994&pmv=print&impressions=false&viewlocale=ja_JP